# Vb6 project not working properly when build with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, vb6, devops

I'm trying to automate a vb6 project deployment through jenkins.

Jenkins server is deployed in Windows Server 2019 running multiple successful jobs.

When I build my project through Visual Studio 6 (for debug), everything is OK.
When I build my project through command line in developer machine, everything is OK.
When I build my project inside Jenkins machine using CMD command, everything is OK.
When I build my project through Jenkins portal, using vb6 plugin, the job is successful, but some screens get wrapped.

Same screen when I build without/with Jenkins:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xrER.png]

If I set the width/height of the form in Form_Load method, I can workaroud the problem, but is a project with tons of forms and I would like to know the source of the problem.

Comment: Hello, are you sure the same source files are used?

Comment: Maybe the Jenkins build process runs with a small video resolution, as if there was a small monitor? AFAICR VB6 can resize forms to a smaller size if they dont "fit" onto the monitor on the machine that is building the EXE

Comment: @Amessihel Yes, I'm sure everything is placed in the correct place. As I said, the problem comes when jenkins does the build. If I log into the machine where jenkins is placed and I build the project manually through CMD everything is correct.

Comment: @MarkJ I have doubt about this one. I connect to the jenkins host through windows RDP. When I do it and I compile through RDP Screen everything is correct. The problem comes when the automatic compilation happends in jenkins. Is there any posibility the java process launched by Jenkins in order to perform the bat process do somethng strange? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It seems possible to me, but I don't have any experience with Jenkins myself. So I am not sure.

Comment: You said _"When I build my project inside Jenkins machine using CMD command, everything is OK."_  Have you run that under the Windows account that Jenkins service _(I assume its a service or something similar)_ runs under? I'm asking, because different users have different "screen resolutions", so that might cause the truncation. This is just a wild guess, though ...

Comment: Are the FRM files being modified by the Jenkins build? Can you see changes to the Form size properties or anything else for that matter?